# How to increase performance for heavy inserts in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I was researching ways to improve mysql performance for inserts.

About the scenario, in a busy day, for every 3 seconds about 3000 rows for big table, another 100 for medium table and around 30 for small table concurrently. This has to be continue for 24 hours and then i'm choosing important part which is only 30.000-40.000 rows then i'm flushing all 3 tables.

So, i'm using mysql 5.5.29. All tables are using innodb, there are few indexes plus primary keys.

About the question, i saw a comment about using memory engine tables for those inserts and then moving them to primary tables:

"using LOCK TABLE .. WRITE may speed up the insertion, but when processing as well as loading rows, you will lock out any reader. A select on primary key (which should take close to 0 seconds) takes up to 0.2 seconds when my loader is busy loading batches of 1000 rows.

A very good workaround is to put the new rows into a temp table, then flush that table every now and then in a single tansaction. This makes the insert very quick, because all the checking and conversion was already done in the temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..._temp (....) ENGINE=MEMORY;

-- Loop from here --
DELETE FROM .._temp;
INSERT INTO .._temp ... VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO .._temp ... VALUES (...);

LOCK TABLE ... WRITE, ..._temp READ;
INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ..._temp;
UNLOCK TABLES;
-- Repeat until done --

DROP TABLE ..._temp;
```

What I've seen in my system, is that the INSERTs go at about the same speed as when locking the table, but the clients do not notice any performance loss at all when the loader is running."

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)

Is that makes sense to using memory engine in that case ?
Should i use innodb for avoding table locks in case of need to access rows or should i prefer to myisam for speed ?

Comment: So these are batch inserts and not 1000 unrelated inserts per second? How are you actually doing the inserts, via SQL calls to server or via a loader (i.e. `LOAD DATA INFILE`)? If SQL, are these single row insert statements multiple row insert statements?

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, batch inserts and related-similar inserts. Actually, i'm using codeigniter's active record library and it's splits batch inserts 100 rows per insert.

Comment: Hang on I just reread.  Is the problem you are concerned with specifically about performance when moving the selected data (30-40K rows) into an archive table? So you want to "empty out" the big table once per day, but need to get some specific rows out of it before doing so.  You also don't want to interrupt the new days' inserts into the big table while this process is ongoing? Does this summarize the problem?

Comment: @MikeBrant For every transaction per 3 seconds: 

1- Truncate memory tables (whic are similar copies of 3 innodb tables btw)
2- Get datas, make inserts into memory table.
3- Select from memory tables, move it to innodb tables.

Is that really an effective way to handle db operations ? That's my main question.

Comment: I don't see what you are gaining by putting data into memory tables.  You still have to get it into the main table at some point. And your use case still seems very unclear to me.  I still don't understand the problem you are trying to solve I guess.  I also don't understand how the data is generated. It seems like it might be data you already have stored somewhere if you know you will be inserting 3000 rows every 3 seconds (86M rows per day).  At that point I can tell you that doing so 100 rows at a time via SQL commands isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @MikeBrant my goal is decrease cpu and memory usage, avoiding table locks making transactions and web-site faster. The idea of using memory tables comes from a comment in dev.mysql.com. The owner of this comment claims: "What I've seen in my system, is that the INSERTs go at about the same speed as when locking the table, but the clients do not notice any performance loss at all when the loader is running." This comment belongs to 2005. I am curious about today.Can there be a performance improvement by using memory tables for inserts and by moving rows from table to table ?

Comment: I Don't see how storing this data in memory tables as well as in insert buffer is going to improve your CPU usage or memory usage if that is the goal. I thought the problem was around query performance on the table while doing your operations? If that is the case utilizing MORE memory (depending on your current memory settings) may actually be a viable solution.  You could also need to look at upgrading CPU or get faster disks as you clearly have a large write load. So decreasing memory/CPU utilization while increasing performance may be impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to wipe your table daily, but need to get data out of it first.  The best bet would be to just quickly swap out the existing full table with a new empty table and then do whatever data operation you need on the full table afterwards.  Here's how you do it.

First create a table just like the table you are trying to operate on:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table_temp LIKE big_table;
```

You now have an empty table with same schema as the big table.

Then rename the tables to swap them out:

```
RENAME TABLE big_table TO big_table_archive, big_table_temp TO big_table;
```

The beauty of this is that this operation is basically instantaneous, as MySQL just renames the binary database files on disk.  Make sure you have both rename operations in one query like this as you want the operation to succeed or fail as a whole.

You can then operate on `big_table_archive` as you want, extracting data out of it, without worrying about blocking live queries on `big_table`.